# Getting signature for vimeo api

Tags: java, android, eclipse, vimeo

This is my code to get the oauth tokens and authorize my app for vimeo. This works fine:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setContentView(webview);

        Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Vimeo servers");

        try {

            final OAuthHmacSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSigner();
            signer.clientSharedSecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET_VIMEO;

            OAuthGetTemporaryToken temporaryToken = new OAuthGetTemporaryToken(Constants.REQUEST_URL_VIMEO);
            temporaryToken.transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
            temporaryToken.signer = signer;
            temporaryToken.consumerKey = Constants.CONSUMER_KEY_VIMEO;
            temporaryToken.callback = Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL;
            OAuthCredentialsResponse tempCredentials = temporaryToken.execute();
            signer.tokenSharedSecret = tempCredentials.tokenSecret;

            OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl authorizeUrl = new OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl(Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL_VIMEO);
            authorizeUrl.temporaryToken = tempCredentials.token;
            String authorizationUrl = authorizeUrl.build();
            Log.d("urlop", authorizationUrl);

            /* WebViewClient must be set BEFORE calling loadUrl! */  
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  

                @Override  
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,Bitmap bitmap)  {  
                    System.out.println("onPageStarted : " + url);
                }
                @Override  
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
                {  
                    Log.d("url", url);
                    if (url.startsWith(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                        try {

                            if (url.indexOf("oauth_token=")!=-1) {

                                String requestToken  = extractParamFromUrl(url,"oauth_token");
                                String verifier= extractParamFromUrl(url,"oauth_verifier");

                                signer.clientSharedSecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET;

                                OAuthGetAccessToken accessToken = new OAuthGetAccessToken(Constants.ACCESS_URL);
                                accessToken.transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
                                Log.d("abc", "");
                                accessToken.temporaryToken = requestToken;
                                Log.d("abc", accessToken.temporaryToken);
                                accessToken.signer = signer;

                                accessToken.consumerKey = Constants.CONSUMER_KEY;
                                accessToken.verifier = verifier;
                                Log.d("abc", accessToken.verifier);

                                OAuthCredentialsResponse credentials = accessToken.execute();

                                signer.tokenSharedSecret = credentials.tokenSecret;
                                Log.d("abc", signer.tokenSharedSecret);
                                CredentialStore credentialStore = new SharedPreferencesCredentialStore(prefs);
                                credentialStore.write(new String[] {credentials.token,credentials.tokenSecret});
                                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                performApiCall();
                               // startActivity(new Intent(OAuthAccessTokenActivityVimeo.this,Vimeo.class));
                            } 
                            else if (url.indexOf("error=")!=-1) 
                            {
                                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                new SharedPreferencesCredentialStore(prefs).clearCredentials();
                                startActivity(new Intent(OAuthAccessTokenActivityVimeo.this,MainMenu.class));
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("onPageFinished : " + url);

                }
                private String extractParamFromUrl(String url,String paramName) 
                {
                    String queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf("?", 0)+1,url.length());
                    QueryStringParser queryStringParser = new QueryStringParser(queryString);
                    return queryStringParser.getQueryParamValue(paramName);
                }  

            });  

            webview.loadUrl(authorizationUrl);  
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, in `performApiCall()` I need to do this:

```
String url = String.format("http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2&format=json&full_response=1&method=vimeo.videos.search&oauth_consumer_key=%s&oauth_nonce=fb86e833df995307290763917343ae19&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1350908218&oauth_version=1.0&per_page=20&query=umar&sort=newest&summary_response=1",
                                            Constants.CONSUMER_KEY

                                            );
```

How can I get `oauth_nonce`, `oauth_timestamp` and `oauth_signature`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220295/vimeo-advanced-api-how-to-connect-via-oauth  does this help you ? or this http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#oauth

Comment: no actually i am successful in authenticating with the vimeo... The only problem is how to pass this query because I dont know the values of my oAuth Session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced

> If you’re totally unfamiliar with OAuth, we recommend that you read
>   [hueniverse’s OAuth 1.0 Guide](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/) before you continue. OAuth is
>   complicated, and he does a great job of explaining the process.
>   [Twitter’s guide](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth) is also very good.

Also watch the following resources (may help you)

- http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#official-libraries
- http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced
- http://vimeoapi.tumblr.com/
- http://speckyboy.com/2012/10/31/coding-a-vimeo-api-instant-search-app-with-jquery/

Comment: mate, I have sucessfully authenticated with vimeo using google oauth api. However I can't figure out how to get signature timestamp and nonce.

Comment: @s.d yes i did, inface google api create its own signate to authenticate. Once authenticated i have no idea how to get these values. That;s what my question is :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Re `oauth_timestamp`: AFAIK, you **set the timestamp yourself** to the current timestamp. If you run into problems (vimeo expects the timestamp to not differ more than a few seconds before or after what it thinks is the current timestamp, cf. [the vimeo forum thread here](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:22100)), try fiddling with the system time you use (e.g., server time).
2. Re `oauth_nonce`: The nonce value is a "random string, **uniquely generated by the client** to allow the server to verify that a request has never been made before" ([The OAuth 1.0 Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.3)).
3. Re `oath_signature`: **The client generates its own signature**. From [The OAuth 1.0 Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#page-18):

> The client declares which signature method is used via the
> "oauth_signature_method" parameter.  It then generates a signature (or
> a string of an equivalent value) and includes it in the
> "oauth_signature" parameter.  The server verifies the signature as
> specified for each method.

**In short: you don't "GET" these values from somewhere, you'll have to create them.**

I'd really like to refer you to [The OAuth 1.0 Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) once again, it's fairly easy to read and should get you sorted for most of the queries you might have :).

Hope this helps.