# Basic PHP Vimeo Advanced API Call

Tags: php, authentication, vimeo-api

**This is a self Q&A.**

I've often looked around for help on using the Vimeo API, and always found the entry level examples and documentation very difficult to follow. So I've written this Q&A as help to those that need it. So here is the question:

**How do I use the Vimeo PHP "Advanced API" to get all of my Vimeo videos?**

The key is "my" videos. This is useful for people building a site that they want to synch with their own Vimeo account. The Vimeo examples are all geared towards allowing a 3rd party user to authenticate as needed. This is a one time static authentication example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Include the Vimeo API file. Download from here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib
require_once('vimeo.php');

/*
 * Helper Function to Handle Vimeo Authentication
 */ 
    function authenticate_vimeo(){
        // Settings below.
        // You'll need to set these to your account's as show here: // Get from https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new

        $vimeo_id = 'user12345'; // Get from https://vimeo.com/settings, must be in the form of user123456
        $consumer_key = '1234567';
        $consumer_secret = '1234567';
        $token = '1234567';
        $token_secret = '1234567';

        // Do an authentication call        
        $vimeo = new phpVimeo($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
        $vimeo->setToken($token, $token_secret);        
        $vimeo->user_id = $vimeo_id;

        return $vimeo;
    }   

/*
 * This is how you make a call to the Vimeo API
 */ 
    // Authenticate Vimeo
    $vimeo = authenticate_vimeo();

    // Try to access the API
    try {
        $args = array(
            'full_response' => true,
            'user_id'       => $vimeo->user_id, // This limits the request to the one user's videos
            'per_page'      => 50, // 50 is the max per page, use "page" parameter for more pages
        );
        $results = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getUploaded', $args); // List of methods here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods
    }
    catch (VimeoAPIException $e) {
        $error = "Encountered an API error -- code {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}";
    }

    // Do something with error or results
    if( isset($error) ) {
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        print_r($results); // This will be a gigantic PHP object of all videos and meta data
    }
```

Comment: Hi what about  $token_secret ?

Answer (score 1):

Visite https://github.com/leandrocfe/PHPVimeoAPI_List_Private_Video

> List private videos from Vimeo | Access private videos

1. Modify config.json info vimeo account;
2. Access video.php and
   add vimeo_video_id get param. Ex:
   localhost/vimeo/video.php?id=123123123

   ```
   <?php

   //utf-8
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

   //lib vimeo
   use Vimeo\Vimeo;

   //métodos de inicialização
   $config = require(__DIR__ . '/init.php');

   //vimeo video id
   @$id = $_GET["id"];

   //isset get
   if(isset($id)){

       // vimeo class send config.json paramns
       $lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);

       //get data vimeo video
       $me = $lib->request("/me/videos/$id");

       //iframe vídeo
       $embed = $me["body"]["embed"]["html"];

       //edit video size
       $default_size = 'width="'.$me["body"]["width"].'" height="'.$me["body"]["height"].'"';
       $new_size = 'width="420" height="220"';

       $embed = str_replace($default_size, $new_size, $embed);

       //autoplay
       $embed = str_replace('player_id=0', 'player_id=0&autoplay=1', $embed);

   }else{

       echo("Not find get id video");
   }
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>Vimeo Vídeo</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div><?php echo $embed ?></div>
           <div>
               <p><b>Name: </b><?php print_r($me["body"]["name"]); ?></p>
               <p><b>Description: </b><?php print_r($me["body"]["description"]); ?></p>
               <p><b>Link: </b><?php print_r($me["body"]["link"]); ?></p>
               <p><b>Likes: </b><?php print_r($me["body"]["embed"]["buttons"]["like"]); ?></p>
               <p><b>Data Created: </b><?php print_r($me["body"]["created_time"]); ?></p>
               <p><b>Data Modified: </b><?php print_r($me["body"]["modified_time"]); ?></p>
               <p><b>Images: </b>
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["uri"]); ?> |
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["sizes"][0]["link"]); ?> |
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["sizes"][1]["link"]); ?> |
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["sizes"][2]["link"]); ?> |
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["sizes"][3]["link"]); ?> |
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["sizes"][4]["link"]); ?> |
                   <?php print_r($me["body"]["pictures"]["sizes"][5]["link"]); ?>
                   </p>
           </div>
           <div><?php //print_r($me); //use for show all options ?></div>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```